# VS Project requires version of .NET that is not used

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I just launched a VS project that I launched many times in the past, but suddenly I get an error message that surprises me:

> You must install or update .NET to run this application.
> App: {PATH TO MY PROJECT}.exe Architecture: x64 Framework:
> 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.0' (x64) .NET location:
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\
>
> The following frameworks were found:
> 5.0.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> 6.0.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

But I updaded my project to .NET 6 already some months ago, so its strange for me that it complains about Microsoft.NETCore.App ***2.1.0***.

So I was wondering if maybe a NuGet Package that I installed also has any dependency on this old version.
Is there any way how I can traverse my .NET 6 project to find the dependency that still requires 2.1.0?
How can I find out the dependency that might cause this issue in my dependency tree?

[image]

What could cause this problem to appear so sudden?

Comment: I have seen some occurrences of this issue when the new version of the .Net framework gets launched, the users may get this kind of error. I would suggest you try to install the latest version of the .Net framework and see whether it helps to fix the issue. Further, you need to check the dependencies one by one and you need to check their documentation to see whether any of them is dependent on .Net framework 2.1

Comment: So VS itself does not show me for a NuGet package which version it refers? I already reinstalled VS 2022 and also .NET...

Comment: If you go to Nuget Package Manager then it will show you the version of the installed packages and it shows you whether there is any update available for those packages. It will not show you whether any packages are dependent on .Net Framework 2.1. for testing purposes, I would suggest installing the latest version of the .Net framework. It may help you fix the said issue.